# Clang: gnu standard library requires -fcoroutines but clang only supports -fcoroutines-ts

Tags: c++20

It seems like the clang compiler flags are currently not compatible with the gnu standard library. Is there still a way to use coroutines?

Comment: You are right, indeed. The clang's version is still in std::experimental and still a technical specification. The gcc implementation seems to be a bit more mature at this point in time with the `-fcoroutines` flag. I've resorted to using gcc for the present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite accurate to say that GCC's header requires `-fcoroutines`, what it actually requires is for the `__cpp_impl_coroutine` macro to be defined by the compiler, indicating that the compiler supports C++20 Coroutines. With GCC, you activate that support by using `-fcoroutines`.