# Is clang-11's invocation of <coroutine> headers via -fcoroutines flag?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to compile a .cpp file that uses the `coroutine` library with the command.

```
clang-11 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libstdc++ main.cpp
```

I get an error like this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/coroutine:295:2: error: "the coroutine header requires -fcoroutines"
#error "the coroutine header requires -fcoroutines"
```

So, I add the flag:

```
clang-11 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libstdc++ main.cpp -fcoroutines
```

Now, I get the error:

```
clang-11: error: unknown argument: '-fcoroutines'
```

Is this a bug?

The closest question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525567/clang-gnu-standard-library-requires-fcoroutines-but-clang-only-supports-fcoro). However, I wasn't able to conclude whether a bug exists or not.

For what its worth, here's the source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>

template<typename T>
bool is_prime(T number) {
    for(int i=2;i<number;i++) {
        if (not i%number) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class prime_iterator {
    unsigned int number = 2;
public:
    auto operator*() const {
        return number;
    }

    prime_iterator& operator++() {
        ++number;
        if (not is_prime(number)) {
            co_yield number;    // Trying to invoke co_yield just to see if library works.
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

auto main() -> int {
    for(prime_iterator p; *p < 30; ++p) {
        std::cout << *p << " is prime";
    }
}
```

Comment: It works with gcc

Comment: Yes. But I'm trying to find evidence to file a bug report for clang.

Comment: Any update on this I have the same problem on clang 10

Comment: Here's a response from Pavel. https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48172

Comment: I am having this problem with clang 12. When I switch to libc++ like Pavel says there is not even a coroutine header. I get the same response with -fcoroutines-ts
clang-12 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'coroutine' file not found
#include <coroutine>''

Answer (score 1):

It should be -fcoroutines-ts for clang. Unless you are building coroutine with clang mixed with libstdc++.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on godbolt

Comment: This is only for use with libc++ not stdlibc++